# shellexecutew "runas" does not provide total full access to registry?

Tags: python, winapi

Why in python

```
shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, u"runas", u'regedit.exe', u'', None, 1)
```

Does not provide full access to registry (some branches are not shown)?
For example:

```
"HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Sensor\Overrides\{BFA794E4-F964-4FDB-90F6-51056BFE4B44}"
```

not exists in this case, only in regedit, run from "Run" menu

Comment: There is no difference between using `runas` and the Start Menu's "Run" menu.  The same elevated process is run either way.  Something else is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 64-bit versions of Windows there are two versions of RegEdit.exe. When you start RegEdit.exe from a 32-bit process you will most likely start the 32-bit version of RegEdit.exe and you will only see the 32-bit view of the registry (The keys under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` etc. in 64-bit RegEdit).

You can verify this by running [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and checking the "Image Type" column when starting it from the Start Menu and from your application...